# Moving windows explorer windows to a set location

Tags: c#, windows, explorer

I have an application which requires windows to be moved to a specific location on the screen.  I have the following code to accomplish this.

```
 //get an array of open processes
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

        //clear the list of open window handles
        WindowHandles.Clear();

        //loop through each process
        foreach (Process process in processes)
        {
            //check if the process has a main window associated with it
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
            {
                //add this process' handle to the open window handles list
                WindowHandles.Add(process.MainWindowHandle);
            }
        }

        //move windows
        AutoMoveWindows();
```

Here are the methods which actually move the windows.

```
  private void AutoMoveWindows()
    {
        foreach (IntPtr handle in WindowHandles)
        {
            //check if the handle has already been moved
            if(!MovedHandles.Contains(handle))
            {
                //move the window to the top left of the screen, set its size to 800 x 600
                MoveWindow(handle, 0, 0, 800, 600, true);

                //add the handle to the moved handles list
                MovedHandles.Add(handle);
            }
        }
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
```

This works fine for all windows except those that are part of explorer.exe such as the file browser or folder properties.  Since it seems explorer.exe doesnt have any kind of "main window" how can I go about detecting these windows, so I can move them?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to just close all explorer windows? Something like `Taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F`?

Comment: Sadly no, this is an application for performing updates/installing software in computer labs.  A user sits at one computer, and everything they do is mirrored on  every computer in the lab, thus having everything line up is fairly important.

Comment: That's too bad. That's certainly one way of doing things, but it seems like scripting would be quite a bit easier. What applications are you updating? Can they be run from the command line with switches?

Comment: We do have a lot of things scripted/automated, however there are several programs such as a particular testing service for example (this is a school environment) that must be updated by hand very frequently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ShellWindows to get the list of windows owned by the shell, and then move each; it would be a separate flow from what you've got above, but it should work. Note that you need to add references to `shell32.dll` and `shdocvw.dll` (in Windows 7 both are in c:\windows\system32).

```
private void MoveAllExplorerWindows(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename;

    foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer window in new SHDocVw.ShellWindows())
    {
        filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(window.FullName).ToLower();
        if (filename.ToLowerInvariant() == "explorer")
        {
            window.Left = 0;
            window.Top = 0;
            window.Width = 800;
            window.Height = 600;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just plugged this into a test application and it seems to be working.  Thank you!

Comment: No worries - you're welcome.  Note the small edit to remove the unused variables.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly late to the game, but I thought this project may be of interest as it addresses the OP's question, how to set the location of Windows Explorer windows.  The project is configurable and able to handle other application types as well.  It seems relevant as the OP seemed to be interested in moving all windows, not just Windows Explorer windows.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1057230/Windows-Resize-and-Move